# Conversion to 12-hour format is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I wrote that code below to convert AM/PM to 12-Hour conversion. This code work fines for `AM` but it is not working for `PM` and generates error that `Provided string for conversion is invalid`. Please anyone answer my question?

```
string st = "10:01 PM";
DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact(st, "H:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan ts = t.TimeOfDay;
editslug.Text = t.TimeOfDay.ToString();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because `H` is the 24 hour clock. You need to use `h`.

```
DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact(st, "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I also argue that you might be looking for `hh` if times come in like this `01:14 AM` for times less than `10`. <strike>However, I don't know enough about your data to be sure about that.</strike>

Comment: For the last paragraph, NO, single `h` would deal with both, single digit and double digit hour part, like `1`, `01`, `10` etc. Same is the case with day and month. Actually it is safer to use single letter for parsing.

Comment: @Habib, noted. I'll strike it based on your comment.